# Get element's coordinate if having locator

Tags: robotframework, appium-ios

How do you get coordinate of the element if you have the locator? That means you can use appium-desktop to get the locator find coordinate by script. If I have A's coordinate because I can guess coordinate of many elements around of A which can't find the element or coordinate.

Answer (score 3):

Appium has a method that allows you to retrieve the screen location of an element using its locator.

http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/attributes/location/